# Live dashboard with lambda and dynamo

Tags: d3.js, jenkins, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

So I want to create a live dashboard (probably a node based app, with react front end). This dashboard will display performance data from a series of websites from the data gathered using Googles Lighthouse Performance audit tool.

The Lighthouse tool published a JSON file with a bunch of keys and values for performance analytics.

I will using something like d3 or chart.js to eventually render this data.

My issue is with how to provide this "live" data to the web front end.

here is my idea so far (just need to know if it is viable.)

1. A Jenkins job will run my dockerised scrit which uses the lighthouse adk to give it a site and return a json performance report.
2. The jenkins job will put the json file into an S3 bucket.
3. A lambda will be triggered each time an item is added to the S3 bucket
4. The lambda will extract the desired values from the json report and write these to dynamo db
5. Dynamo DB stream will be used to get the latest values from the dynamo table.
6. The web front end will query the dynamo DB streams and render the data into chars and graphs.

Can you see this process working? would this give me a sort of "live" data feed? the idea is that the performance reports will be created multiple times during the day

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the DynamoDB stream will work the way you think, unless I'm totally misunderstanding something about DynamoDB streams. How would DynamoDB push streaming data to a web browser?

---

I would recommend having the Lambda function add a timestamp to each record it inserts into DynamoDB. Have the timestamp field be the sort key for the primary index of the table.

Next have another Lambda function that queries the DynamoDB table for the latest record(s) using the timestamp field. Expose that Lambda function via API Gateway.

Finally have the web front-end make API calls to the endpoint you created in API Gateway to retrieve the latest performance data.

Comment: Thanks for the info mark, I thought the a DynamoDB Stream was designed to take the latest inputs from DynamoDB and surface that, then a web front end could query the stream. But maybe I am wrong.

I like the idea of the second lambda querying Dynamo, that way I could make a request to a specific set of values. like make a request fro data from site 1 and site 2 etc.

Comment: The DynamoDB stream *pushes* the data somewhere. Like it could trigger a Lambda function with every updated record. The streams don't sit there waiting for things to query them.

Answer (score 1):

"live" can mean different things to different people and for infrequently changing data (a few times a day is not frequent compared to an interactive chat) the overhead of managing sockets, etc. might not be worth it compared to simply refreshing the page.

I don't see why you need Dynamo here; you can just read from S3 directly and perhaps use versioning on objects to track the different stats for each run.

If you genuinely want browser-based notifications you can look in to AWS IoT, and have a Lambda subscribed to the S3 bucket where the results are run that extracts the values and publishes them to IoT, which can expose a web socket for your browser based app.